# PHP string to double typecast sets zero

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have something like 
var_dump($value) is

> string(10) "45000"

$value = (double) $value;

and echo $value; outputs 0

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code.

Code:

```
echo "before: ";
echo var_dump($value);
$value = (double) $value;
echo "after: ";
echo var_dump($value);
```

Output:

> before: string(10) "45000" after: float(0)

Comment: `string(10) "45000"` Do you see something weird here? Try this: `$value = (double) trim($value);` and OR go into View source code and tell use the output which you see there

Comment: tried... same result...

Comment: Show us the output from your source code, what you see there!

Comment: view source is same 0..

Comment: Oh... its float(0)..

Comment: The output which you show now is this from your source code? And if yes please check it with a hex editor because somewhere somehow you have some hidden characters in there

Comment: Yup from the source code.

Comment: I see.... I have already checked for it.. Is there any other way to identify hex char?

Comment: Well I though about some html tags, but maybe you have other weird characters in there which you don't even see there, so put the output into a hex editor and check it there. Also please add how you get this value/variable

Comment: If I convert to hex it works fine... Probably not true.. .but  at least it converts

Comment: Please show us how you get this value! So show us your **full** code

Comment: It is coming from database and set as class variable.. $this->value; nothing else... otherwise I would have put the code.. there is no manipulation of the $value before that nor referenced anywhere.

Comment: Check the encoding from your string, and tell it

Comment: WT*... if I do echo preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $value); it returns null as well...

Comment: It is ASCII encoding....

Comment: Please add your **full** and **real** code how you get the value from your db and so on

Comment: I cannot its over so many files. I understand you cannot tell without it but this acting really strange.... Haven't faced anything like this in last 6 years...

Comment: Well another thing is: [How to fix stuff working in IT](http://itsfunny.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/How-I-fix-stuff-working-in-IT.jpg) Try the blue and red thing :D

Comment: Also please add a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). BTW: You get `float(0)` as output even if you cast it to double? Please check that! <-

Comment: All fine and dandy, but you fail to show us where and how `$value` is defined. `$value = 45000;` and `$value = "45000";` are two different animals. `$value = (double) $value;` doesn't qualify as being "defined".

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce same result with some custom variable i.e. $testVar = "     45000";  and then cast it to double ?

Comment: Just one more thing after this I'm out of ideas at this point. How did you viewed the source code? (Right click -> view source code) ?

Comment: One wierd thing if I do echo ord($value{1}); it return 112... any ideas?

Comment: Did you read my last comment? And what is the output of: `echo ord($value[0]);` ? Is it 60 ?

Comment: And `echo ord($value[2]);` ? Also don't forgot `@username` so that I get a notification if you write something to me. And How did you viewed the source code?

Comment: @Rizier123 its 114.. Of course I did right click view source.. I checked with firebug as well..

Comment: Please do this: `echo ord($value[X]);` and change X from 0 to 9 and tell me a list with every value

Comment: @Rizier123 there you go mate... `36,112,114,105,110,99,105,112,108,101`

Comment: Do you have a variable in your code named: `$principle` ?

Comment: Yup.... I have it...

Comment: How did I know that :D? And `var_dump($principle);` = output (from the source code) is?

Comment: Holy ****... What the **** is happening....

Comment: Undefined variable: principle as it is on the other file.. but how it is referenced to value... that is big question....

Comment: I'm already surprised that you get that via: `echo ord($value[X])`. So 1. When you include the file the variable should be in scope 2. Did you checked the value which you get from your DB in your DBMS? 3. Please please show us the code how you get the data.

Comment: I have codeigniter framework with our library in it which fetches data and renders xml layouts... therefore it is not possible to put it here.. the questoin I have is why it is not outputing $principle but 45000

Comment: *codeigniter framework* ARE you kidding me? After 2 hours you want to tell my that? And you didn't even tagged it with this!

Comment: OMG.... I am damn sorry @Rizier123... I did not notice that I have not tagged codeigniter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description you have given and the LONG comment discussion I am making a wild guess.

Check the output of debug_zval_dump if you get reference count more than 0 it means your variable is carrying reference from somewhere and that variable is modified in the process.

Secondly do you have any javascript that is changing the variable on load or on certain event.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thank god... someone tried to answer... debug_zval_dump is 3. Is there any way I can check which variable is that...

Comment: Dude.. that variable has to be $principle as thats what you are getting in ord()..

Comment: lol...@user3089273 is that javascript issue?? You should have tagged and should give enough information otherwise no one will be able to help you

Comment: I am checking my javascript... but I feel most likely it is javascript as I am using this code to populate table data using ajax..

Comment: AJAX table population... dude(if you are)... you should have mentioned it the first place... you must be replacing the value...

Comment: I put that branch on hold and it was so silly of me to end up modifying javascript... I am feeling really bad..

Comment: It is OK.. make sure you give proper description and complete scenario.. that how you learn.. should be fine...